# How To Show Coplanarity of 3 vectors in 4D?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

- I was trying to understand when 4 equations in 2 variables can have a unique
  solution. In the column picture this would mean that all 3 vectors I
  am working with must be co planar.
- When I do gaussian elimination I get that all rows except the first
  two have zeroes and the top 2 rows look like an upper triangular
  matrix, the 3rd column also has zeroes except the first two entries.
- If I had been working with 3 equations in 2 variables I am able to
  intuitively see that all rows including the one on the RHS together
  form a 3x3 matrix (augmented) and if the bottom rows are zero that matrix
  signifies that scalar dot product is zero and hence the vectors are
  coplanar

I am not able to in a similar way intuitively see how the 4x3 matrix (augmented) proves the coplanarity of said 4D vectors.

PS: I know that the vectors could be multiples of each other (|axb|=0, a,b are not zero vectors) and we may have infinite solutions but i am taking the 2 columns to be linearly independent.

Comment: What are these $3$ vectors you are talking about in your first bullet point ?

Comment: the vectors that would be formed if we interpret the linear equations system as a linear combination of 2 vectors.  as in one example i was doing was [1,1,1,1], [-4,-3,-2,-1],[-3,-2,-1,0]

Comment: I think this is closely related to the theorem which states that the column rank of a matrix is equal to the its row rank

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand in your description, you have the linear system

$ A x = b $

where $ A $ is $ 4 \times 2 $ , $ x $ is $ 2 \times 1 $ , and $ b $ is $ 4 \times 1 $.

And you are assuming that the two columns of $A$ are linearly independent, and that the system has a unique solution $x$.

What this means, is that the augmented matrix

$ [ A | b ] $

has column rank equal to $2$.

But [according to this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)), the column rank is equal to the row rank.

Therefore, out of the $4$ row vectors of the augmented matrix (which are $\in \mathbb{R}^3$) exactly two are linearly independent.  Hence these $4$ vectors lie in the same plane that is spanned by these two independent vectors.

Comment: Makes sense. Is there no way to understand it by trying to work with the coplanarity  of the 3 vectors in 4 D (column vectors) since that is the main issue I was facing ?

Comment: May there are other ways to look at the problem, but I am unaware of them.